# Setting the values of html dropdownlist using JQuery by passing arguments

Tags: jquery

I have two dropdownlist for which I have bound data from database.

```
<tr>
            <td>
                <label for="ddlCountry">
                    Country</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="ddlCountry" name="ddlCountry">
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="ddlCurency">
                    Currency</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="ddlCurrency" name="ddlCurrency">
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

i have bound data to these data using Jquery

For ddlCurrency:

```
var $html1 = '';
                $html1 += '<option value="">---Select Currency---</option>';
                if ($currencyList != null || $currencyList != '') {
                    $.each($currencyList, function (index, item) {
                        $html1 += '<option value=' + item.Currency + '>' + item.Currency + '</option>';
                    });
                }
                $('#ddlCurrency').append($html1);
```

For ddlCountry:

```
var $html = '';
                $html += '<option value="">---Select Country---</option>';
                if ($countryList != null || $countryList != '') {
                    var $i = 0;
                    $.each($countryList, function (index, item) {
                        $html += '<option value=' + $i + '>' + item.Country + '</option>';
                        $i++;
                    });
                }
                $('#ddlCountry').append($html);
```

Now the problem is that when I programatically try to select the dropdownlist item ,there is the problem. There is no problem with data binding. **When i pass arguments to the value which in my case comes from grid(not asp.net gridview)  only ddlCountry shows the item with passed argument but  ddlCurrency shows ---Select Currency--- which is my first item in ddlCurrency meaning it does not select anything.**

here is the code for selecting dropdown item by passing arguments.

```
$('select[id=ddlCountry] option:contains(' + argus[5] + ')').attr('selected', true);
        $("#ddlCurrency option[value=" + argus[6] + "]").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Only first one selects dropdownlist item with desired item and second one does not select anything but **both args have values**

now when i do this :

```
$("#ddlCurrency option[value=" + 'USD' + "]").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

it selects item in dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place `argus[6]` in single quotes here ([**Attribute Equals**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector):

```
$("#ddlCurrency option[value='" + argus[6] + "']")
```